# Is it possible to use an Arduino accelerometer to rotate an Android screen?

Tags: android, arduino, usb

I have installed Android 4.2.2 on a ARM board, Orange Pi (A20). I have also an [accelerometer](http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1764146) based on Arduino Nano (ATMega328) to communicate with the system, via serial USB (UART).

Is a chance exist (with some work!) to make this accelerometer active to rotate the screen, and better, to play with ?

Comment: Yes you can, you can do anything with coding :D

Comment: Hehe! XD - Thanx for this hope !!

Comment: I worked on a robot controlled with arduino/android, so based on what i learned this is totaly possible, you should just make your android and arduino communicate, back then i used a wixel for wireless communication : https://www.pololu.com/product/1336

Comment: I read that many people says that the ATMega328 chip is not really supported by Android. I have seen this library : https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android but the chip is not supported :( So bluetooth is the only way

Comment: well if you use wireless comunication dont think you'll have a problem, Android support wirless and so is Arduino Nano, Tough you can communicate :). i dunno about USB...never tested sorry ^^.

Comment: Allwininner-based Android devices typically talk to an i2c/twi accelerometer chip directly.  Your MPU-6050 is i2c based - why not skip the Arduino ATmega and connect your sensor to the A20's i2c/twi?

Comment: Because no app exist (as I know) to control GPIO for this board. So, I try to get the datas with USB/serial ... But I'm not very good specialist I must say.

Comment: i2c is not GPIO.  There are already i2c drivers for your board, though they may not be active in your build. The functionality would not be part of an "app".

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you for all this precisions, I'm building a new kernel with mpu3050 and I²C to see what happend. Now, to seach how to plug directly the device !

Answer (score 0):

I managed to receive some datas.

**1)** Build cp210x.ko in the kernel, and insmod it in Android

**2)** With the Arduino application on Ubuntu, I have programed the chip with the example "MPU6050_raw" (from [here](https://code.google.com/p/mw-wingui/downloads/list)) and adding a delay (and incidentally a sensor value)
If the delay is not set, the Orange freeze. It's the begining of my tests..

```
        // blink LED to indicate activity
    blinkState = !blinkState;
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, blinkState);

    // read the input on analog pin 0:
    int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
    // print out the value you read:
    Serial.println(sensorValue);
    delay(2000);        // delay in between reads for stability
}
```

**3)** On Android, with the app [SerialPort_1.1.apk](https://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/downloads/detail?name=SerialPort_1.1.apk), set the device `/dev/ttyUSB0` and the baudrate to `38400`.
Here is the result:
[image]

This is a start, now I think the most difficult will be to create my app to treat theses datas...

Comment: Normally, rotation is determined by a system driver.  An app can be written to utilize or ignore that information in its own display, but it would not be normal for an app to try to set rotation of the device overall.  That said, I'm sure someone has made some sort of fixed-rotation widget for rooted devices before.

Comment: I havn't found a such script, only a MPU6050's ino file (for Arduino) to display the real angles: https://github.com/helscream/MPU6050_Arduino/blob/master/README.md
But no app!

Comment: It would not be a script, but rather a kernel driver and an Android daemon.  No "app" is involved.  You might start with the mpu3050 gyro driver https://github.com/LeMaker/linux-sunxi/blob/lemaker-3.4/drivers/input/misc/mpu3050.c and add capability to read the 6050's acceleration registers which the 3050 lacks.  Then you could look at one of the other acceleration drivers that is already integrated with Android for screen rotation.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. I will see this way. Seems more 'easy'. And for the connection, no USB as your idea ? Just I²C/twi ?